# keras model stops training after first step of epoch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning but am looking to employ the [3D-RCAN](https://github.com/AiviaCommunity/3D-RCAN) neural network to denoise microscopy images. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble training this network properly on my computer. My machine's hardware and software environments are:

- Windows 10
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5220R CPU, 128 GB memory
- NVIDIA RTX A6000 GPU, 48 GB memory
- CUDA v11.2 with cuDNN v8.1.1.33
- NVIDIA Driver 511.09
- Python 3.9.7 in an Anaconda environment
- tensorflow 2.8.0 and tensorflow-gpu 2.8.0

The network was written and tested in tensorflow_gpu==1.13.1. I have been able to train the network on my older computer, with a less powerful GPU, by reproducing the environment of the authors. However, I cannot do this on my my new computer with a more powerful GPU. By making some small modifications to the code, I've gotten the network to complete the training without an error message. I sometimes (but not always) receive the warning message

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py:830 RuntimeWarning: Failed to sample a valid patch."
```

It is clear that the network is not functioning properly- it appears to stop the training after the first step of the first epoch if I set the `steps_per_epoch` hyperparameter to be greater than 1. If `steps_per_epoch=1`, then the training does complete.

My major question, then, is what could be causing the network to stop training after the first step when `steps_per_epoch>1`? I've been looking into potential issues with the `data_generator` but haven't been able to figure out whether this is the root cause. The generation is being done with a Keras sequence object to generate batches indefinitely.

A potential clue is that the GPU memory usage appears to spike to 100% just as the function is exiting. This is unexpected because this behavior does not occur on my old computer with far less GPU memory (6 GB).

Comment: Hi@etrs !  Source code depicts the steps_per_epoch is dependent on number of Gpu's . Can you let us know after replacing the GPU with a fixed count like 2 . You can lower the batch size /add more pooling layers and constrain  the memory growth to resolve the GPU issues. Attaching relevant threads. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/set_visible_devices

Comment: Hi, @TensorflowSupport thanks for your reply!

When replacing `steps_per_epoch // gpus` with a fixed positive integer, the training only completes if just 1 step is taken. If `steps_per_epochs>1`, the training fails to complete. 

It appears that the code is breaking in '`enumerate_epochs` in line 1194 of [data_adapter.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py). This is due to `self.insufficient_data` being set in `catch_stop_iteration`. Do you know the underlying reason it might be running out of data?

Comment: Regarding the links you posted above, when I attempt to constrain the memory growth, I get Runtime Error: Runtime is already initialized. It's not clear to me where the gpu would have been initialized, though, since I inserted the lines before `get_gpu_count` in `train.py`.